# Application always on top with no focus on mac os x

Tags: macos, qt, focus

I'm trying to correct some bugs on my Qt application porting it from Snow Leopard to Lion. On previous Mac OS X versions (Leopard, Snow Leopard) I succeed having my application always on top letting the focus to the previously selected application.

It had the same behavior as the "Keyboard Viewer" in the system available Input Methods of Mac OS X. For this I filtered the events sent to my app through the `macEventFilter(EventHandlerCallRef caller, EventRef event)` and used the `qt_mac_set_raise_process(false)` accessed through `extern void Q_GUI_EXPORT` when receiving a mouse down event on my app. My window attributes are the following ones: `widget->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)`. I tried adding Qt::Tool attribute but did not get what I had.

Anyone did this ?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of QT are you using? Is it Qt Cocoa/Carbon ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm using 4.8 beta compiled from sources with default configuration means cocoa 64 bits.